# very big bigquery table to python list

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have a table in bigquery with more than 50 million rows. I want to take a single column from the table and load it into a python list.

I am currently using the following code to convert my query to a list:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

bq_client = bigquery.Client()
query = """ SELECT column FROM table GROUP BY column """
query_result = bq_client.query(query)
column_list = [row.column  for row in query_result]
```

It is way too slow / causes memory issues.

Are there better ways of doing this?

Comment: I suspect to get a proper answer to this you'd need to explain what exactly you're intending to do with your list. Some use cases may have simple solutions (e.g. lazy generation, rather than populating the whole list at once). Other uses may be impossible without a machine with much more memory or processing power, or much more clever algorithms.

Comment: realised loading every row of the table into a single list was a terrible idea. I ended up exporting the big query table to smaller, more manageable csv files in cloud storage.